# Opening a File from Windows Application C#

Tags: c#, file, windows

I am trying to open a file (it could be word/excel or any other type of file) from my windows application. I do Not want to read the file contents using FileStream but want to open the file like one would just double click the file to open and it opens the file in its respective application.

Could any one help me to achieve this from c# code?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the class [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Have you done any research yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("yourFilePath");
```

Comment: If a question has already several duplicates in StackOverflow, you better flag it as a duplicate, instead of answering it.